# Scroll 2D/3D background via texture offset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, offset, tiling

I have been trying to make an infinite scrolling 2D background in Unity using a quad to display a Texture. My idea was to change the offset of the quad depending on the player's position. For some reason when I change the offset my image does not repeat properly and once an offset of 2 has been reached completely disappears.

[An image of 3 different x offset values on my texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7eNY.jpg)

If anyone knows how to fix this if you could get back to me it would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the original Texture not the GameOBject.

**1**. Change **Texture Type** to **Texture**.

**2**. Change **Wrap Mode** to **Repeat**.

**3**. Click Apply. Done!

[image]

Latest version of Unity menu for Textures has changed. See the below image:

[image]

Now to animate the texture from script,

**1**. Create a Quad `GameObject -> 3D Object ->Quad`. Scale the Quad to the size you want

**2**. Create a light. `GameObject->Light->Directional Light`. You can adjust the light Intensity to whatever you like.

**3**. Drag your Texture/Sprite to the Quad in the Scene View.

Now for your script:

```
public GameObject quadGameObject;
private Renderer quadRenderer;

float scrollSpeed = 0.5f;

void Start()
{
    quadRenderer = quadGameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
}

void Update()
{
    Vector2 textureOffset = new Vector2(Time.time*scrollSpeed,0);
    quadRenderer.material.mainTextureOffset = textureOffset;
}
```

---

For 2D, you can also use a *Plane* or *Quad* from the *GameObject* ---> *3D Object* menu and the code above should work fine.

Comment: Thanks Programmer my background is scrolling properly now ;)

Comment: @TommyEaves You are welcome. I was wondering if it worked or not.

Comment: @TommyEaves No problem.

Comment: ah wrap mode wasn't on!  brilliant, @Programmer

Comment: @JoeBlow It could be just that but no one knows how he was also moving the texture and didn't want to hear that it was not working too so I threw both the Texture and the moving code part together just in-case he was doing any of them wrong. Based on the picture he provided, it looks like wrap mode problem.Thanks.

Comment: Note that not all Unity built-in shaders work, although they have offset exposed as editable. The ones I could successfully test were "Unlit/..." (Unity 2019.1)