# I have a bug in the renderer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class Scroll : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 0.5f;

    void Update()
    {
        Vector2 offset = new Vector2(0, Time.time * speed);

       renderer.material.mainTextureOffset = offset;

    }
```

i didn't understand where the problem is, but it is supposed to be in the renderer.material part.

I have put this code in a Quad to try and make it my background.

edit: error messages : 
- Assets/Scroll.cs(12,8): error CS0619: `UnityEngine.Component.renderer' is obsolete:`Property renderer has been deprecated. Use GetComponent() instead. (UnityUpgradable)'
- Assets/Scroll.cs(12,17): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Component' does not contain a definition for`material' and no extension method `material' of type`UnityEngine.Component' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- nable to parse file Assets/Game scene.unity.meta: [Control characters are not allowed] at line 0

Comment: Add Exception\Error message

Comment: if `Time.time` a delta between two frames? of just a time. because the `y` value will increase over time. You might want to calculate the delta between the current and the previous update.

Comment: You probably want `Time.deltaTime` which is the elapsed time between two frames.

Answer (score 0):

You can no longer access `renderer` that is inherited from `MonoBehaviour` directly. You must use `GetComponent` to get the `Renderer`. The-same thing applies to other components such as `Rigidbody` and `AudioSource`.

```
Renderer myRenderer;
public float speed = 0.5f;

void Start()
{
    myRenderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
}

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update()
 {
     Vector2 offset = new Vector2(0, Time.time * speed);
     myRenderer.material.mainTextureOffset = offset;
 }
```

Of-course, `GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTextureOffset = offset;` could have worked too but it is better to cache it like I did in the first script.

Comment: Also, as mentioned by `muXXmit2X`, it should be `Time.deltaTime * speed`.

Comment: @GunnarB. `Time.time` should be used for this because it increments each second. In order to move texture offset, you have to use a variable that increments or decrements constantly. That's not what `Time.deltaTime` is used for. `Time.deltaTime` is used for smoothing out values. `Time.time` is appropriate for [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-mainTextureOffset.html).

Comment: @Adem, make sure to change `Texture Type` to `Texture` then change `Wrap Mode` to `Repeat`. More information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36948841/3785314).